# Set page numbering in InDesign (with extendscript)

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

In InDesign, I can set the page numbering options to start at any number. Like this (starting at 5):

[image]

Please note that this is not the same as page markers as text in the document. I need to change it in the Pages panel.

My question is: How can I do this with ExtendScript? I have figured out how to read it from the active page:

```
app.activeWindow.activePage.name
```

But I want to change it, something like this:

```
i = 1;
for each page
  app.activeWindow.activePage.name = i;
  i++;
end
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
app.activeDocument.sections[0].continueNumbering = false;
app.activeDocument.sections[0].pageNumberStart = 5;
```

and have a look at these links:

http://yearbookmachine.github.io/esdocs/#/InDesign/Section/continueNumbering
http://yearbookmachine.github.io/esdocs/#/InDesign/Section/pageNumberStart